# where can i get authentic list of ip address range according to country?

Tags: php

hey guys i am looking for the list of ip address ranges according to country. for my project

Comment: http://xkcd.com/195/ might be helpful (it's only five years old).

Comment: You need to be aware that such lists are only guidelines - for example I'm in the UK but my work IP address shows up as being in the USA because I work for an american company that routes my internet access via their US facilites. So you need to be aware that IP address don't always neatly map to a country, this may or may not be a problem for you

Comment: thanks for your help..but then whats the other way to track the visitor's country?

Answer (score 1):

I use the csv provided by maxmind- http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite

Answer (score 0):

You can find from here. [List 1](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/)   [List 2](http://www.find-ip-address.org/ip-country/)